# Getting an error while trying to access app.user on a twig templay symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

Im trying to access to app.user.username on my twig template.

Running Symfony3.4.

My auth is working so that should not be the problem.

This is the code:

```
{% extends "@Foro/layout.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}

{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    <strong>You're a normal user</strong>
{% endif %}
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    {% app.user.username %}
    <strong>You're an admin</strong>
{% endif %}
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <h2>Identifícate</h2>
    <hr/>
    <form action="{{ path("login_check") }}" method="POST">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="username" name="_username"  class="form-control" />
        <label>Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password"  class="form-control" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Entrar"  class="btn btn-success" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/login" />
    </form>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

I get the following error:

> Unexpected "app" tag (expecting closing tag for the "if" tag defined
>   near line 8).

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: are ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN cumulative ? otherwise, you could use a `elseif` instead of the second `if` on line 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write it like that :

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i was getting mad :)